# Speed up the processing of large amounts of data

Tags: php

In order.
I have a large database of domains in text format.

1. I process the file itself and add the domains to the database (about 20 thousand in 30 seconds). The problem is in the second paragraph.
2. After processing, I start the process of reading domains from the database, then processing through CURL (leaving only sites with a response of 200) and reading the source code page.
   The process of checking 20k domains took about 3 hours. Despite the fact that all this time, the site did not work. Just threw a timeout.

Question: is it possible to speed up this process? (run the script recursively) or is it realistic to at least leave the web server in working condition during the processing process (the server is powerful, but for some reason it crashes anyway).

The logic of the script (paragraph 2).

```
if($_POST['start'] == "true") {
    //...
    //SELECT DATABASE
    //...
    while($allRows) {
        $line = $allRows['INPUT_URL'];
        //...
        // GET CURL STATUS 200, IP adress and HTML code
        //...
        if($status == "200") {
            // strpos HTML code
            //...
            //add answer to another Database
        }
    }
}
```

Curl settings:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgents[array_rand($userAgents)]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

Comment: you could spawn multiple (background) processes which can perform your curl operation. This way you could operate multiple processes at a time and also keep up with the timeouts because every check should not take more than a couple seconds and after it, it could be closed.

Comment: add set_time_limit(0); at starting of php file

Comment: Are there any examples of how to create these background processes? I will be grateful

Comment: @Omar, This parameter is set.

Comment: You can use python to do this task easily

Comment: @Omar - That doesn't help with the speed of the script. It will only make sure the script doesn't time out, which they haven't mentioned it doing.

Comment: @ScreamX maybe this will help: https://www.gem3s.com/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-background

Comment: @MagnusEriksson background process also does not speed up the script. It does only take the execution in the background, and not halt the next statement.

Comment: @Omar - What does that have to do with your `set_time_limit()` comment, which is what I referred to? I haven't mentioned or claimed anything about background processes.